# Macro Throwing error while running during closing - Sub or Function not Defined

Tags: vba, excel

I have three macros which are placed in the sheet 2 of the excel sheet. I want to run the macro whenever the excel sheet is closed. I used the following code,

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Macro1
    Macro2
    Macro3
End Sub
```

where the Macro1, Macro2 and Macro3 are macros in sheet2. This code is placed in ThisWorkBook part of the excel sheet. When I execute this I get an error,

```
Compile Error:
    Sub or Function not defined
```

Suppose the sheet2 has name "Nameofsheet2" , Can anybody help me how to solve this problem? I want the macros in the sheet2 to run whenever the excel sheet is closed.

Thanks

Comment: is there a reason why you don't put macros 1 through 3 in a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your macros code on a Module and it will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

well the simplest way is to call them like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    SheetX.Macro1
    SheetX.Macro2
    SheetX.Macro3
End Sub
```

Where `SheetX` is the internal code-name of your Sheet2 (this is the name that you see in the Project Window of the VBA IDE, it may not be the same name as shown in the Excel sheet tabs)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a macro from a workbook that's not the current one, just use `Application.Run [workbook]!MacroName`,

i.e. `Application.Run "Personal.xlsb!clearImmediateWindow"`

If it's stored in another sheet, use `Sheet2.MacroName`.